# How to execute linux command in php code

Tags: php, linux, lamp

I need to copy one file one location to another location 
Example:

```
<?php
$file="welcome.mp3";
$location1="/var/www/html/upload/audiofile/$file";
$location2="/var/lib/sounds/en/";
exec(cp $location1 $location1);
?>
```

i need to run linux cp command in exec(). How to execute this process.

Comment: What have you tried? I can't see any `exec` call... just assigning these values to variables isn't going to exec anything

Comment: Why do you want to shell out? PHP has [a copy function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) built-in.

Comment: you can use system or exec. For copy use php copy function.

Comment: @SaravananMP: What makes you say I down-voted? Besides: Read the [help on how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and the tool-top on down-votes: _"this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"_. Those are reasons to down-vote, and they _do_ apply to your question, IMO. Since your new I _did not_ down-vote your question, hoping you'd edit your question, but since you're going all defensive, and accuse me of down-voting, and demand to _tell the answer_... well, I have half a mind of down-voting you just for being rude

Answer (score 2):

See [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

> string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )

The first argument of `exec` must be a string.

You also need to make the destination different to the source for there to be any point in doing this.

```
exec("cp $location1 $location2");
```

As mentioned in a comment though, don't shell out for things [PHP has built-in](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the backtick ` (top left on US keyboard)

```
$moved = `cp $location1 $location2`;
```

(Although Quentin's answer is a better idea.)